# FBX to XNB on a Mac: is it possible?

Tags: 3d, xna, monogame, fbx

I am running Mac OSX 10.8, and am developing a new, 3D game in MonoGame (Xna for Mac). The problem I have run into is that MonoGame uses XNB files, to add support directly from Xna. MonoGame can compile 2D images and textures, but 3D models must be converted to XNB format. I have been doing some reading, and it looks like this is impossible on a Mac alone. You need the Xna framework installed to do the conversion. My question is: are there any other ways to convert FBX files to XNB files on a Mac alone? I do have WINE installed, if that is any help. I also absolutely do not have access to a Windows with Xna installed, only Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, you are right... Currently it is [not possible on Mac](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/432219) using Monogame while there are ways to do it over Windows... But Monogame team surely have been working over this since around 6 months and I'm sure they will develop something pretty soon... You can follow their discussion [here](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/1209)

In the meantime, I would suggest you to try your hands over [ManagedFXB](https://github.com/returnString/ManagedFBX) if you are a non commercial identity... All the best then...